# i have a code that is running correctly but it is not showing any output

Tags: java

There is no error in my code but don't know why no output is visible.

The code is to sort the words within a sentence for example "hi how are you" look likes "are hi how you".

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> words_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean once_entered = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lines.add(i, scan.nextLine() + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

         String word = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.get(i).length(); j++) {
            char char_0 = lines.get(i).toLowerCase().charAt(j);
            if ((int) (char_0) >= (int) ('a') && (int) (char_0) <= (int) ('z')) {
                word += char_0;
             once_entered = false;
            } else if (!once_entered) {
                words.add(word);
                word = "";
                once_entered = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        boolean contains =false;
        for(int j=0;j<words_2.size();j++){
            if(words_2.get(j).contentEquals(words.get(i)))
                contains=true;
        }
        if(!contains)
            words_2.add(words.get(i));
    }
    Collections.sort(words_2);
    System.out.println(words_2.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < words_2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(words_2.get(i));

    }
}
```

Comment: `if ((int) (char_0) >= (int) ('a') && (int) (char_0) <= (int) ('z'))` please avoid unnecessary casting and just use `if (char_0 >= 'a' && char_0 <= 'z')`.

Comment: Btw you're code runs and it shows output. I hope you didn't forgot, that you need to input `n` and your words/Sentences, before it shows something, right?

Comment: Thanks Tom but I am still not getting any output. My question is still same why I am not getting any output.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code with corrections.

Comment: And how do you run your programm? With which IDE/application?

Comment: *"Can you please provide me the code with corrections."* There is nothing to correct, since it is already working. You can improve the above mentioned check, though.

Comment: How to input n and sentences.

Comment: That depends on how you run your program.

Comment: What do you mean by *"is running correctly but it is not showing any output"*.  Do you mean that it doesn't complete?  Do you mean that it does complete, but it produces absolutely no output?  Do you mean that it completes but outputs nothing apart from the size of `words_2`?  Please describe the symptoms CLEARLY.

Comment: *"Can you please provide me the code with corrections."*  - Absolutely not.  This is >>your<< homework ... not ours.  Debugging your code is part of your homework.

Comment: your code is fine what do you use as input?

Comment: its not waiting for input

Comment: it is showing the following errors now -at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at rowmatch.row.main(row.java:15)